# Python Gitlab API - attributes

Tags: gitlab-api, python-gitlab

Using python Gitlab API, how to list merge requests filtered by some attributes ?

For instance, using curl I can use attributes in my request like `?author_username=MY_NAME&source_branch=MY_BRANCH`.

But I cannot find those attribute in the documentation (https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the python-gitlab landing page you linked to states:

> `python-gitlab` enables you to [...] pass arbitrary parameters to the GitLab API. Simply follow GitLab’s docs on what parameters are available.

So you can just pass the GitLab APIs to the list call. Example:

```py
import os

import gitlab


gl = gitlab.Gitlab(private_token=os.getenv("GITLAB_TOKEN"))

# Instance level
mrs = gl.mergerequests.list(
    author_username=AUTHOR_USERNAME,
    source_branch=SOURCE_BRANCH,
)

# Project level
project = gl.projects.get("your-group/your-project", lazy=True)
project_mrs = project.mergerequests.list(
    author_username=AUTHOR_USERNAME,
    source_branch=SOURCE_BRANCH,
)
```